# Google Cloud HTTP function by webhook: Request body is missing data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, zoom-sdk

Im integrating the Zoom API with my Firebase app, and to do so I'm relying on Zooms pre-made webhooks to run an HTTP function on my Firebase for various events like "meeting started" and "meeting ended". Zoom API reference: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/webhooks

This is the Google Cloud function that the Zoom API is calling:

```
exports.zoomTestA = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    let data = req.body;
    var xmlData = data.toString();
    console.log(xmlData);
});
```

Here is the payload sent by Zoom:

```
{
  "event": "meeting.ended",
  "payload": {
    "account_id": "LTf-KjgUTR2df-knT8BVEw",
    "object": {
      "duration": 0,
      "start_time": "2019-05-07T14:02:51Z",
      "timezone": "",
      "topic": "Alexander Zoom Meeting",
      "id": "864370042",
      "type": 1,
      "uuid": "2h/SWVrrQMu7fcbpLUly3g==",
      "host_id": "Ty6ykNolSU2k1N4oc0NRcQ"
    }
  }
```

This causes this error to appear in my Google Cloud console:

```
Request body is missing data. { event: 'meeting.ended',
  payload: 
   { account_id: 'LTf-KjgUTR2df-knT8BVEw',
     object: 
      { duration: 0,
        start_time: '2019-04-30T14:23:44Z',
        timezone: '',
        topic: 'Alexander\'s Zoom Meeting',
        id: '837578313',
        type: 1,
        uuid: 'WotbHO3RRpSviETStKEGYA==',
        host_id: 'Ty6ykNolSU2k1N4oc0NRcQ' } } }
```

The request body that Zoom sends is not wrapped in in a "data: {}" tag as required by Google Cloud functions. I've found solutions to this problem if you can control the payload here: [Dart json.encode is not encoding as needed by Firebase Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181995/dart-json-encode-is-not-encoding-as-needed-by-firebase-function) .

My problem is that I am unable to alter the request that the Zoom API sends. Is there any way I can still accept the request in my Google Cloud function? Or is there any way to alter the format of the request sent by Zoom? I'm unable to find references for either.

One potential solution would be to set up another server that receives the request by Zoom, format it to Google Cloud functions specifications, and then pass it on to my Google Cloud function. I would however like to avoid stepping out of the Google Cloud eco-system.

Is this problem solvable on the Google Cloud platform?

Comment: Show us the code that you use to send to Firebase.

Comment: I've added the code of the Firebase function and the Zoom payload, but as mentioned the problem is that I do not control the request sent by Zoom.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So I figured it out. In Firebase / Google Cloud functions you can either make HTTP-functions with

```
functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {
  var data = req.body;
```

and

```
functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var data = req.body;
```

The difference seems to be that `onCall` is made for being used within the Firebase/ Google Cloud functions environment. However if you wan external functions you need to use `onRequest` as this does not require specific formatting of the payload.

Using `onRequest` instead solved all my problems.

Comment: When you change from `onCall` to `onRequest` the `req` object is slightly different. With `onCall` `req` itself actually contains any post parameters passed to the function, while with `onRequest` you need to get `req.body`. Also with `onCall` you can return a JS object, but with `onRequest` you need to do `res.json(returnData)`. Just discovered this when converting my own function and wanted to help out anyone else who runs into the same issue.

Comment: Actually callable function has a different signature `(data: any, context: CallableContext) => any | Promise<any>`, you can check it out in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https#oncall